# Uploading files on amazon s3 using gulp.js

Tags: gulp

Has anyone found a good solution for automatically uploading the static assets (i.e. what's in the build directory) to Amazon S3 in an automated way after they are compiled, and then retrieving them from the app?

Answer (score 0):

There is [gulp-awspublish](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-awspublish) that can be integrated to a Gulp workflow to handle automatic uploads to S3. I don't know how well it's maintained though.